# ElasticSearch as EventStore

Tags: elasticsearch, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I would like to ask you about your opinion and what you see as cons and pros to use ElasticSearch as EventStore.

I would like to hear if somebody had experience with using ElasticSearch as event store and what was the results, reliability and if there was any issues.

Comment: The question is what do you want/need to do with those data afterwards? How many events are you expecting? You can store (almost) anything in ES so there's no right/wrong answer to your question.

Comment: As good example we will use it to rebuild views, to generate different views for different endpoints. There is huge amount of data about promotions, prices and changes and so on. So expectation are huge but history is very important also. So storage should handle lot of requests, and be reliable. Because history is very important for generating and rebuilding views.

Comment: Does elasticsearch provides a mechanism to version your streams (and use the version to detect concurrency conflicts) and query events per streams to reconstruct aggregates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eta: Reminded of this post by a no-explanation-down-voter... [This Kafka is not for Event Sourcing](https://medium.com/serialized-io/apache-kafka-is-not-for-event-sourcing-81735c3cf5c) post is pretty useful when thinking through this sort of a question.

---

Elastic search is simply not designed to be an authoritative persistent store for actual app state.
Neither is Redis.
Neither is Kafka.

All three may potentially be useful in the context of an app which does employ an event store.

May I suggest reading a book like [NoSql distilled](http://martinfowler.com/books/nosql.html) to get an idea of selection criteria in this space so you'll know how to select something appropriate.

Also for a question like this to be more answerable (in general questions like this are considered subjective and get closed), it's important to supply context as to what sort of stuff you're going to maintain, what sort of access patterns, what sort of scale and/or any other context. A laundrly list of contextless pro/cons is not going to help much.

Comment: Thanks for response I will take a look into that book. Question was more in general, as we doing actually research what to use as event store for project what we are doing in work. We read about dynamo DB from amazon but it was also not suitable solution so I have tried to ask if someone have experience with elasticsearch in such a case. Simply we're developing data-service where we stroing events about: prices, price changes, promotions and generating views to endpoint from that data. Also if something fail to re-generate views from events. Thanks for your response it satisfied me enought.